# Why Android Emulator still crashes when moving it between displays if gpu mode is "hardware" (host)

Tags: android, android-emulator

Why Android Emulator still crashes when moving it between displays if gpu mode is "hardware" (host)?

I tested this with Intel CPU + Nvidia GPU, Intel CPU and AMD GPU and also with AMD CPU and AMD gpu. On all of those setups, Android Emulator just crashes (freezes) righ away while moving it to secondary display.

Any idea why this is still hapenning? Solution is to just switch to software acceleration, but that stresses the CPU pointlessly.